# Can a Half-Giant Soulknife manifest Mind Blades of the Large size category?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, creature-size

*Note: I am aware that I am quoting from 3rd party materials, and not core Pathfinder stuff.*

[The Soulknife's ability Form Mind Blade says the following:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife)

> A soulknife must choose the form of her mind blade at 1st level. She can either form it into a light weapon, a one-handed weapon, or a two-handed weapon. Once chosen, her mind blade stays in this form every time the soulknife forms her mind blade. The light weapon deals 1d6 points of damage, the one-handed weapon deals 1d8 points of damage, and the two-handed weapon deals 2d6 points of damage. All damages are based on a Medium-sized creature wielding Medium-sized weapons; adjust the weapon damage as appropriate for different sized weapons. In all forms, the mind blade has a critical range of 19-20/x2. **A soulknife with powerful build or any similar ability forms an appropriately-sized mind blade dealing the size-appropriate amount of damage.**

Emphasis mine. [The Half-Giant's Powerful Build trait reads as follows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/races/half-giant):

> Powerful Build: The physical stature of half-giants lets them function in many ways as if they were one size category larger. Whenever a half-giant is subject to a size modifier or special size modifier for a Combat Maneuver Bonus or Combat Maneuver Defense (such as during grapple checks, bull rush attempts, and trip attempts), the half-giant is treated as one size larger if doing so is advantageous to him. A half-giant is also considered to be one size larger when determining whether a creature's special attacks based on size (such as grab or swallow whole) can affect him. **A half-giant can use weapons designed for a creature one size larger without penalty.** However, his space and reach remain those of a creature of his actual size. The benefts of this racial trait stack with the effects of powers, abilities, and spells that change the subject's size category.

Again, emphasis mine. Does this mean that a Half-Giant can create Large mind blades because they can use them and are therefore appropriately-sized (and the rules for the Mind Blade say this because it doesn't say medium-sized only), or does it mean that they can only use Medium sized Mind Blades? From what I can tell, the difference in damage for a two-handed weapon would be 2d6 VS 3d6.

Comment: Incidentally, the ability never mentions weapon size apart from saying that "damages are based on a Medium-sized creature wielding Medium-sized weapons", meaning that the weapon size is up to the Soulknife to decide on. That is, *unless* you have Powerful build, in which case you "(form) an appropriately-sized mind blade"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes.

The soulknife ability clearly states that if a soulknife has Powerful build the knife it manifests is larger to match the ability. So you would deal increased damage due to having a larger knife than say.. a regular human.

By design this also means if you can find a way to get Enlarge Person to increase your size, then you would also benefit from the soulknife damage increase granted by powerful build as well.

Form Soul blade states:

> A soulknife must choose the form of her mind blade at 1st level. She can either form it into a light weapon, a one-handed weapon, or a two-handed weapon. Once chosen, her mind blade stays in this form every time the soulknife forms her mind blade. The light weapon deals 1d6 points of damage, the one-handed weapon deals 1d8 points of damage, and the two-handed weapon deals 2d6 points of damage. All damages are based on a Medium-sized creature wielding Medium-sized weapons.

This constrains the Soul blade to a certain type of weapon, such as longsword, shortsword, trident, etc. Whichever you choose when you first manifest it. The size changes based on your own size, which may have variable scaling.

Comment: This would be an interesting follow-up question, would the mind blade increase in size dynamically if you did? Since it states you have to choose it at 1st level and it stays the same, it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

Powerful build is an unusual feature; there are only six ways to get it:

- Five from Dreamscarred Press

  - half-giant (race; *Ultimate Psionics* and [SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/races/half-giant/))
  - dreige (race; *Bloodforge*)
  - oggr (race; *Bloodforge*)
  - Mighty Frame (feat; *Bloodforge*)
  - an astral suit option for the aegis (class; *Ultimate Psionics* and [SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/))
- one by Open Design

  - dogmole juggernaut (an Int-2 animal who lacks the ability to wield weapons anyway; *Midgard Bestiary for Pathfinder RPG* and [SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/dogmole-kp/dogmole-juggernaut-kp/))

This being the case, the fact that Dreamscarred Press wrote all of these playable options, as well as soulknife, means it’s really safe to assume that they specifically had the half-giant in mind when they wrote Form Mind Blade.

> A soulknife with powerful build [i.e. a half-giant] or any similar ability forms an appropriately-sized mind blade dealing the size-appropriate amount of damage.

What, in context, would be appropriate? The size weapon that such a creature can use without problem. For a half-giant, that means a Large weapon, and so they form Large-sized mind blades.

Comment: I count six ways. 5 from DSP, 1 from OD.

Comment: @ShadowKras Should have directed that to Powerdork, who edited in more options I had missed. Anyway, fixed.

Comment: I know, but typing his name here wasnt autocompleting so i thought he wouldnt be notified.

Comment: @ShadowKras I figured *Bloodforge* should only count once. While half-giant came in the first Pathfinder psionics book (*Psionics Unleashed*), the aegis class came in the second (*Psionics Expanded*). Also, thanks for reminding me to update my profile.